# How does the Reduced Level Requirement affix interact with other gear?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does an item with its level requirement reduced only affect the item with the affix, or does it affect all items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It affects only the level requirement of the item its on, and its already factored in when you hover over the item.  So if you see a level 45 weapon with -15 level requirements, its actually originally a level 60 weapon.

Comment: Note that when searching in the auction house, you would not see the level 45 item if you were e.g. searching for items level 40-50.  You need to search for "Reduced Item Level Requirement" specifically and look for items higher than your level.

Answer (score 0):

yx's answer is entirely correct, but [this sale post](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/46112-us-1h-spear-6894dps-lv-48-req/) demonstrates its potential for twinks.